# Perl's rand() function with localtime as seed

Tags: perl, random, random-seed

Please look at the following piece of code:

```
srand(localtime);

for (my $ik = 0; $ik < 3; $ik += 1)
{
    print int(rand(10)),"\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

I invoke the above piece of code multiple times with sufficient time(5-10 sec) in between, still the output sequence is the same.

As I have set the seed to `localtime` every invocation must use a different seed and perhaps generate a different sequence of three numbers, because of the time gap. Why do I get the same sequence again and again.

Note: The code is NOT in a loop, it is in a Perl file which is being executed multiple times.

The documentation says that this seed fails if multiple instances run in the same 'second' leading to the same seed - here it is not the case.

EDIT:: The solution by @simbabque does help but the randomness expected is not gained. Look at my comment on the aforementioned solution below.

Comment: Which OS are you on? In general, if you care about the quality of your pseudo random number generator, you should not be using the built-in `rand` (i.e. whatever the C runtime gives you) but one with known *good* properties.

Answer (score 7):

Try running this with [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html). It will give you:

`Argument "Thu Jun 21 13:04:41 2012" isn't numeric in srand at ...`

And right there is your problem. [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) returns a string in scalar context. Try using [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) instead, which returns the unix timestamp as an integer. [`srand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html) needs a numerical value to work.

If you add a [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) to it you'll see that the seed with your code is always `1`.

```
no strict; no warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper srand(localtime);

for (my $ik = 0; $ik < 3; $ik += 1)
{
    print int(rand(10)),"\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

Says:

```
$VAR1 = 1;
0
2
6
```

What you need is:

```
use strict; use warnings;
srand(time);
for (my $ik = 0; $ik < 3; $ik += 1)
{
    print int(rand(10)),"\n";
    sleep(1);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

This still is not a very good idea if you want good randomness. The doc says:

> In versions of Perl prior to 5.004 the default seed was just the
>   current time. This isn't a particularly good seed, so many old
>   programs supply their own seed value (often `time ^ $$` or `time ^ ($$ +
>   ($$ << 15))` ), but that isn't necessary any more.

I suggest you just omit the call to `srand` at all unless you actually want reproducable results (i.e. for testing).

Comment: I changed localtime to time but now having run almost 10 instances of this code interleaved with some seconds - all the seq start with 3. This can't be a coincidence.

Comment: I see that, too. If you want more random values, you should not need to call `srand` at all according to the doc because it is called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no reason to expect better randomness by repeatedly seeding a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

You can use the following script to check what's going on with your original question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use 5.014;

for (1 .. 3) {
    my $seq = newseq(3, 5);
    printf "Seed = %s\n", $seq->{seed};
    my $it = $seq->{generator};
    while (defined(my $r = $it->())) {
        print "$r\n";
    }
    sleep 5;
}


sub newseq {
    my ($length, $limit) = @_;
    $length //= 10;
    $limit  //= 10;

    my $seed = srand(time);
    return {
        seed => $seed,
        generator => sub {
            return unless $length-- > 0;
            return rand($limit);
        },
    };
}
```

However, if you do need statistically independent generators, you can use [Math::Random::MT::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT%3a%3aAuto) and create individual PRNG objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use 5.014;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::Random::MT::Auto qw(:!auto);

my $prng1 = Math::Random::MT::Auto->new(SOURCE => '/dev/random');
my $prng2 = Math::Random::MT::Auto->new(SOURCE => 'random_org');

say $prng1->rand();
say $prng2->irand();
```